# Docusign eSignature - This User lacks sufficient permissions

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am trying to setup the Docusign eSignature i nSFDC, through the Docusign APP Launcher and I am getting this error message whenever trying to create an Envelope template : "You are not authorized to access the envelope."

With the following API status in my Docusign API dashboard : ERROR: This User lacks sufficient permissions. :: Setting: userOverrideEnabled.

[[image: see API log error in Docusign].

Does anyone know what could be reason ?

Few more details :

- I've seen in a post from Docusign that the error could come from having "Allow sender to download form data" unchecked. But it did not change anything in my case.
- I'm admin in SFDC, in the Docusign App launcher in SFDC & the user who activated the integration. My email address is not registered as an Admin user in Docusign (im logging as some one else who is the admin in Docusign)

Best,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue your user has to be admin in DocuSign also.